# Nodejs + Socket.IO - how to get total bytes transferred (read/write) after socket close

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a simple socket.io client and server program, running on node.js. The client and server exchange messages between them for a few minutes, before disconnecting (like chat).

If there any function/method I can use to get the total bytes transferred (read/write), after the socket is closed?

At present I am adding up the message size for each each message sent and received by the client. But, as per my understanding, in socket.io depending on which protocol is used (websocket, xhr-polling, etc.), the size of the final payload being sent will differ due to the header/wrapper size. Hence, just adding message bytes won't give me an accurate measure of bytes transferred.

I can use monitoring tools like Wireshark to get this value, but I would prefer using a javascript utility to get this value. Search online, didn't give me any reasonable answer.

For pure websocket connections, I am being able to get this value using the functions: `socket._socket.bytesRead` and `socket._socket.bytesWritten`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As of socket v2.2.0 i managed to get byte data like this. Only problem these are specified when client closes browser window and `reason` parameter is `transport error`. If client uses `socket.close()` or `.disconnect()` or server uses `.disconnect()` then bytes are `0`.

```
socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
        let symbs = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(socket.conn.transport.socket._socket);

        let bytesRead = socket.conn.transport.socket._socket[symbs[3]];
        let bytesWritten = socket.conn.transport.socket._socket[symbs[4]]; 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted such a feature that would work no matter what the underlying transport was below a socket.io connection, then this would have to be a fundamental feature of socket.io because only it knows the details of what it's doing with each transport and protocol.

But, socket.io does not have this feature built in for the various transports that it could use.  I would conclude that if you're going to use the socket.io interface to abstract out the specific protocol and implementation on top of that protocol, then you give up the ability to know exactly how many bytes socket.io chooses to use in order to implement the connection on its chosen transport.

There are likely debug APIs (probably only available to browser extensions, not standard web pages) that can give you access to some of the page-wide info you see in the Chrome debugger so that might be an option to investigate.  See the info for [chrome.devtools.network](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network) if you want more info.